# Filtering ListView generated from JSON

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I have this activity wherein it retrieves data from the `MySQL` database using JSON with volley repository and then displays it in a `ListView`.

Here's the activity where the `ListView` is displayed:

**SearchDestActivity.java**

```
public class SearchDestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public static final String JSON_URL = "http://iwander.pe.hu/sample/sample.php";

private Button buttonGet;

private ListView listView;
CustomList cl;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_dest);

    sendRequest();

    buttonGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);
    buttonGet.setOnClickListener(this);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);

    }

private void sendRequest(){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(JSON_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    showJSON(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(SearchDestActivity.this,error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String json){
    ParseJSON pj = new ParseJSON(json);
    pj.parseJSON();
    CustomList cl = new CustomList(this, ParseJSON.ids,ParseJSON.names,ParseJSON.emails);
    listView.setAdapter(cl);

        }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
```

}

Then here's the java class which displays the contents of the `ListView`:

**CustomList.Java**

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private String[] ids;
private String[] names;
private String[] emails;
private Activity context;

public CustomList(Activity context, String[] ids, String[] names, String[] emails) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_view_layout, ids);
    this.context = context;
    this.ids = ids;
    this.names = names;
    this.emails = emails;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_layout, null, true);
    TextView textViewId = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.route);
    TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.busName);
    TextView textViewEmail = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.terminal);

    textViewId.setText(ids[position]);
    textViewName.setText(names[position]);
    textViewEmail.setText(emails[position]);

    return listViewItem;
}


}
```

I have a `editText` on top of that `ListView` and I want to filter it with the text entered. I tried putting this on my code:

```
listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dest);
    myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 
           cl.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

        }
    });
```

But when I tried entering text the app crashes. The logcat shows this:

[image]

FYI here's a screen cap of the results:

[image]

The text from the `editText` should match the text with the red font color.

**EDIT**

Since the cause of the previous is error is `cl` is not being globalized, I fixed that and the filtering worked. But another problem is that it doen't show the right filtered results just like this one:

[image]

Comment: You never initialize your cl field because when you do *CustomList cl = new Custom...* in the showJSON() method you are creating a local variable. Instead you should write *cl = new Custom...* in your showJson() method.

Comment: Thank you for the response and yes you are right. I changed that part and  somehow the app didn't crash and was able to display the results. The thing is, whenever I type on the editText it filters but it doesn't match with the text with the red color.

Comment: That behavior happens because of the way you setup the adapter. Current flow: you enter a search text-> the adapter filters based on that text and you end up with one element matching(just an example like in your image)-> in your getView() method you bind the data from your **unfiltered** initial list based on the position. So if you get one match you'll get the first element in the list(position 0), if you get two matches you'll get the two first elements(position 0 and 1) etc. Implement your own adapter(along with filtering), ArrayAdapter is suited for very basic scenarios.

Comment: @Luksprog do you have an example for this? Or any project where I can base on?

Answer (score 1):

On your `onTextChanged` method you're getting a `NullPointerException`.

the `cl` object is null 'cause the `showJSON` creates a local variable `CustomList cl`. It have to be global.

Comment: Done that, tried it and it functioned but the filter results are not right. I'll edit my question.